# .htaccess redirect cookie to new url for all ending urls

Tags: .htaccess

So the site detects the cookie = uk okay but when I'm trying to redirect

from: http://example.com/page/page-name to: http://example.com/uk/page/page-name

no url is working the way I was hoping adding in the /uk/ it appears to be adding in a index.php for some reason.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} country=uk; [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/])/uk/?        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What is original URL and what URL should that be redirected to?

Comment: edited my from and to urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} country=uk; [NC]
RewriteRule !^uk/ /uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

Comment: thanks that was exactly the right thing I was looking for